# send youtube live chat messages as different account through api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am designing a chat bot to use for a streamer friend of mine, and I'm running across the issue where I can't/don't know how to make it so my account sends messages to his live stream. In order to access his live chat I use his access and refresh token, however using those tokens causes the message displayed in his live chat to be from his account, even if the api is registered under mine.

I've tried using the access and refresh token of my account and trying to access the live stream that way, but it displays that there is no livestream to be found (its looking for my account to be live).

I know that nightbot is able to achieve what I'm trying to but I don't know if they got special permission by YouTube to do so.